# regular expression not working as i expect it too, something is wrong with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

```
(?<=atr1=\").*(?=\")

<h1 atr1="test1" atr2="test2"
```

I'm expecting regex to grab the value in atr1, but it is grabbing more than that. It stops at double quote after test2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the lazy modifier `*?` to stop at the first double quote:

```
(?<=atr1=").*?(?=")
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cH6nX2/1)

PS: i removed also the escaping for double quotes not strictly needed (unless you have to use a double quoted string)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to grab

```
test1
```

from

```
<h1 atr1="test1" atr2="test2"
```

then:

```
atr1="([^"]+)"
```

will capture it.

Answer (score 1):

Use negation regex and avoid lookahead:

```
(?<=atr1=")[^"]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gZ4tO8/1)

However if you're using a language like PHP, Python, etc then I suggest avoiding regex altogether and use builtin DOM parsers instead.